# WJXBFS1 keyword in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In one of the Oracle queries, I see something like

```
SELECT something, sum(1.0) WJXBFS1 FROM some_table
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a keyword, it is an alias for a calculated value so that you can control the field name rather than having Oracle generate one. Otherwise how would you access that field?

Aliasing in Oracle can be done either with or without an "AS" clause, so think of

```
SELECT something, sum(1.0) WJXBFS1 FROM some_table
```

as being the same as

```
SELECT something, sum(1.0) AS WJXBFS1 FROM some_table
```

so you know that you can reference the column holding the value of SUM(1.0) by the name WJBFS1

Incidentally, you can alias any column - not just calculated ones. For example, this would be perfectly legal..

```
  select a as b, b as a from sometable;
```

Not saying it would be smart! Just saying that it is legal.

Comment: sum(1) will do the same thing as count() as it is summing the value 1 for each row in the query.

Comment: I remember `WJXBFS1` is short for the name initals for some of the developers. Can anyone tell me who they are?